# how to stub a java class method in jruby

Tags: java, ruby, rspec, jruby

I have the following code in jruby:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    start
  end
  def start
    require 'java'
    java_import 'org.priv.Config'
    @config = Config.get('filename.conf')
    bar
  end

  def bar
    @config.read
  end
end
```

I have tried the following approach in rspec:

```
it 'raises on config.read' do
  subject.instance_variable_set('@config', FakeConfig.new)
end
```

In my `FakeConfig` I have a `read` method that `raises`. When I run the tests, there is no exception being raised. Any idea what I am doing wrong and whether I can improve this somehow?

The stub class:

```
class FakeConfig
  def read
    raise # or fatal
  end
end
```